# How about making UnityAnswers part of StackExchange network?

Tags: discussion, area-51, stack-exchange, site-proposal

[UnityAnswers](http://answers.unity3d.com/) is using StackExchange 1.0 and it's about the game engine [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com). Unity3D is a powerful game engine that you can develop on Windows or MacOS and deploy them on Windows, MacOS, Web, Android, iPhone/iPad, Wii, XBox 360 and PS3, which is pretty cool but that's not the point. My point is that there is a wonderful community that is using SE engine and it is more than qualified to be part of the network.

So my question is what can we do to make it part of the network and have a link to it, like with every other SE site?

It should be somehow possible, with a direct collaboration from both companies like it happened with [Ubuntu SE](https://askubuntu.com/). It will attract more traffic and the overall quality of the questions will increase. I was participating there for a long time, while I was playing with Unity, and I would really like to see all the new features of SE implemented there as well and of course getting more love from the main network.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: @badp's I think it's more like Ubuntu.SE and Unix.SE and they can both live alongside, especially if it's going to be possible to merge questions from one to another :)

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new proposal in Area 51 and publicize the proposal wherever it is appropriate to do so on UnityAnswers. If it makes it through to the commitment phase, the [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) community managers should be able to liaise an agreement between the two sites.

Keep in mind that unless there is an overwhelming amount of users showing an actually need to be on the Stack Exchange network, it's unlikely to happen. There are many reasons why a 1.0 site may wish to stay independent or join the existing Stack Exchange network: It's up to the community to decide.

Comment: I think now it's ruined :( the thing is I'm not active in Unity3D anymore.. and I can't really participate! At the moment they switched to this SE clone and I don't think that it is even possible to merge all the questions/answers.. :(